# Net Tie - Design Rule Error in Altium Designer

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

I am designing battery charging system. Datasheet of IC's says "***Connection of switching ground to system ground, or any internal ground plane should be single-point.***" on PCB layout considerations. For this reason I decided to use "**Net Tie**" between *GND* and *PGND*.

I created net tie schematic rectangle(pin1 and pin2) and net tie footprint . You can see below.

When I am using Net Tie on my PCB I have seen **Design Rule Problems**.

> Clearance Constraint(Collision <0.15mm) Between Pad on TopLayer and Track on Toplayer.
>
> Short circuit Constraint Between Pad on Toplayer and Track on Toplayer.

Picture 1:

[image: Net Tie on Schematic]

Picture 2:
[image: Net Tie Footprint]
https://s32.postimg.org/u3ttijdut/footprint.png

Note: Track width is 0.255mm (okey for design rule)

Picture 3:

[image: Screenshot of PCB]

How can I solve the problems? Do you have any advice for this problem?

By the way I checked this pdf:
-Net Ties and How to Use Them-
https://www.smtnet.com/library/files/upload/NetTies-and-How-to-Use-Them.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this problem. This solution may be useful for those who will have the same problem in the future.

**1**. Firstly you have to be careful in the schematic section.

**2**. Open Schematic Library

**3**. Click to your component name(net tie) and you will see Library component properties.

**4**. Change the  "Type" from "Standard" to "Net Tie" .

**5**. Save

**6**. Update your footprints.

**7**. Use it, it will be done.

By the way , don't forget to review this pdf: -Net Ties and How to Use Them- https://www.smtnet.com/library/files/upload/NetTies-and-How-to-Use-Them.pdf